# Why are my images not in one column? What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: html, django

I'm new to the front end world, and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to get my images all in one row, but they are all over the place and my text isn't showing up correctly either.

**matches.html**

```
<div class="container ">
<h2>It's a match!</h2>
<div class = "row">

        <div class="col-4">

             <img src="{{ user.photo.url }}" width= "300" height= "300" object-fit = "cover" >

        </div>
        <div class="col-8">

             <img src="{% static 'images/matching_cupid.png' %}" width= "300" height= "300" object-fit = "cover" >

        <div class="col-12">

             <img src="{{ match.photo.url }}" width= "300" height= "300" object-fit = "cover" >

        </div>

</div>
<p>You and {{ match.username }} like each other!</p>
<p><a href="{% url 'dating_app:messages' user.id %}">Start messaging </a></p>
<br>
<p><a href="{% url 'dating_app:mingle' %}">Keep mingling!</a></p>
```

{% endblock %}

Answer (score 0):

Use col-4 in all classes instead of col-8 and col-12

Or if you are using bootstrap then col-lg-4